# Getting AttributeError while registering my model to Django admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

**What i am trying to do:**

*Trying to registering my model to django admin*

**What problem do i get:**

*I am getting the following error:*

[image: Attribute Error]

**My Code:**

**admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import UserProfile, Post

admin.site.register(UserProfile,Post)
```

**model.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/media/',max_length=100)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content = models.TextField()
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register/$',views.registerUser),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="Index"),
    url(r'^validateRegisterForm/$',views.validateRegisterForm),
    url(r'^validateLoginForm/$',views.validateLoginForm),
    url(r'^article/$', views.article, name="Article"),
    url(r'^Login/$',views.loginUser, name="Login"),
    url(r'^Logout/$',views.logoutUser, name="Logout"),
]
```

**Note: I am new to django so, don't know much about it.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be

```
admin.site.register(UserProfile)
admin.site.register(Post)
```

`Admin.site.register` takes two parameters, the first is the model class and the optional second parameter is an admin class. In your code, you were passing another model as the admin class.

for more information, please refer to :https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: how was my question structured ? is that how you ask questions in a good way ? :D

Comment: your question is a good one. certainly a lot better than the majority of the questions we get here. The only improvement you need to make to future questions is to post the errors as text instead of as images.

Comment: but by posting images you get more information than posting just texts... btw thanks for your kind replies sir, mam whatever you are. ;)

Comment: you are most welcome and glad to have been of help. The topic of whether or not to post images has been discussed in meta.stackoverflow.com and the concensus is stacktraces should be text :)